# Only Admin can Edit, Delete or Update

Tags: admin, user-roles

I want to know if there is any way in WordPress that only Admin can update/edit or delete published posts/listings. User who have submitted the post/listing can't even edit/update or delete it.

Theme: DirectoryPress

Answer (score 3):

Summary of Roles:

**Super Admin** - Someone with access to the blog network administration features controlling the entire network ([See Create a Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)).

**Administrator** - Somebody who has access to all the administration features

**Editor** - Somebody who can publish and manage posts and pages as well as manage other users' posts, etc.

**Author** - Somebody who can publish and manage their own posts

**Contributor** - Somebody who can write and manage their posts but not publish them

**Subscriber** - Somebody who can only manage their profile

Sourse -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities